# httpx.RemoteProtocolError while processign 1Gb+ file

Tags: python, httpx

My code downloads huge file with httpx and process it's chunks on the fly

```py
async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
    async with client.stream("GET", self.url, follow_redirects=True, timeout=60) as stream:
        async for chunk in stream.aiter_text():
            parser.feed(chunk)
            await self._process_element(parser)
```

When I run it on my notebook it works good but in the the kuber cluster on dedicated pod I have got error: `httpx.RemoteProtocolError: peer closed connection without sending complete message body` after about 300K `_process_element()`'s.

Doc for h11 says, that "maximum number of bytes we’re willing to buffer of an incomplete event. In practice this mostly sets a limit on the maximum size of the request/response line + headers. If this is exceeded, then `next_event()` will raise `RemoteProtocolError`." Does it means my code working too slow and cannot manage incoming stream? And the 2nd: can I increase buffer for incoming stream? There is no interface for this in HTTPX as far as I know.

Any advises welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

all of [httpx](https://github.com/encode/httpx/) network functionality is handled by [httpcore](https://github.com/encode/httpcore/), a separate project. Anyway, there is a very dirty way to do it, which I do not recommend, but you can use it for debugging purposes because httpcore does not provide any API to do it the normal way.

```py
import httpcore

httpcore._async.http11.AsyncHTTP11Connection.MAX_INCOMPLETE_EVENT_SIZE = 10**10
httpcore._sync.http11.HTTP11Connection.MAX_INCOMPLETE_EVENT_SIZE = 10**10

pool = httpcore.ConnectionPool()
pool.request("GET", "https://www.youtube.com")
print(pool.connections[0]._connection._h11_state._max_incomplete_event_size) 
# 10000000000
```

with httpx

```py
import httpcore
import httpx

httpcore._async.http11.AsyncHTTP11Connection.MAX_INCOMPLETE_EVENT_SIZE = 10**10
httpcore._sync.http11.HTTP11Connection.MAX_INCOMPLETE_EVENT_SIZE = 10**10

pool = httpx.Client()
pool.request("GET", "https://www.youtube.com")
print(pool)
```

If that helps, you can open an issue in the httpcore issue tracker, and we will provide a user-friendly interface for changing that behavior.